# What are launchd's LaunchAgents directories for?

Tags: launchd, plist

I created some job plist files and put them in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. Now I don't see the point of this special directory (see [launchd manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/launchd)). When I want to load a job, I have to specify a whole path to a plist file. Or can I somehow restart launchd so that it reads those files again?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the key `Disabled` the job definitions in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` will be loaded automatically by `launchd` whenever the user logs in.